# Loading XML file Pyspark on databricks

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am trying to use the databricks spark xml library to import the following XML file: https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/kieranw/Badges.xml.

```
xml_posts = spark.read.format("xml").options(rootTag='badges').load('s3a://%s:%s@%s/Badges.xml'% (ACCESS_KEY, ENCODED_SECRET_KEY, BUCKET_NAME))
xml_posts.printSchema()
xml_posts.show()
```

I'm using databricks notebooks with Spark 2.2.1.

When I try and perform a show nulls are just returned to screen. I'm assuming it's to do with the parser not interpreting the XML file properly. How can I define the schema properly if this is the case?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you've just trying to define the schema, that's available here on databricks xml library
https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml

I've added the library to my cluster (see [this](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/libraries.html) for info) but have had no luck in reading it. I'm not convinced it's the schema though

Comment: Thanks for your response!. Yeah I managed to add the library to my cluster but I can't get the data to load either.